# How to use salsa20 (or ChaCha)?

Tags: c++, c, cryptography

Assume that we have a large file which can be read in chunks of 1024 bytes or so, how can I encrypt and decrypt each chunk using Salsa or Chacha 20?

Also, where would I specify the number of rounds (i.e. 8, 12, or 20)?

So far, I haven't been able to figure it out by looking at the eSTREAM test package :(

I've downloaded the following files via [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/project.html) and the [Salsa20 homepage](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html):

- chacha.c
- ecrypt-config.h
- ecrypt-machine.h
- ecrypt-portable.h
- ecrypt-sync.h

And I see the comments in encrypt-sync.h talk about calling functions in this order:

- ECRYPT_keysetup();
- ECRYPT_ivsetup();
- ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes();

But I have absolutely no idea exactly what I'm supposed to be supplying as parameters to make this work...

Here's my best attempt so far, starting with one small string of plaintext (my C is rusty... it's possible I've made some basic mistake, though I can't see it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "ecrypt-sync.h"

#define CHUNKSIZE 1024

void getRandomBytes(u8 **str, u32 len);
void showData(u8 *data, u8 *header);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char plaintext[CHUNKSIZE] = "THIS IS A TEST";
    ECRYPT_ctx ctx;
    u8 *key, *IV, *ciphertext, *result;

    /*
    Don't use random values till we get it working with zeroes at least
    getRandomBytes(&key, ECRYPT_MAXKEYSIZE/8);
    getRandomBytes(&IV, ECRYPT_MAXIVSIZE/8);
    */

    key = (u8 *)calloc((size_t)ECRYPT_MAXKEYSIZE/8, sizeof(u8));
    IV = (u8 *)calloc((size_t)ECRYPT_MAXIVSIZE/8, sizeof(u8));

    printf("Encrypting [%s] using random %d bit key and %d bit IV:\n", plaintext, ECRYPT_MAXKEYSIZE, ECRYPT_MAXIVSIZE);

    ECRYPT_init();
    ECRYPT_keysetup(&ctx, key, ECRYPT_MAXKEYSIZE, ECRYPT_MAXIVSIZE);
    ECRYPT_ivsetup(&ctx, IV);

    ciphertext = (u8 *)calloc((size_t)CHUNKSIZE, sizeof(u8));

    ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes(&ctx, plaintext, ciphertext, CHUNKSIZE);

    //showData(ciphertext, "CIPHERTEXT");

    result = (u8 *)calloc((size_t)CHUNKSIZE, sizeof(u8));

    ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes(&ctx, ciphertext, result, CHUNKSIZE);
    printf("And now decrypting back: [%s]\n", result);

    return 0;
}

void showData(u8 *data, u8 *header) {
    printf("\n-----BEGIN %s-----\n%s\n-----END %s-----\n", header, data, header);

}

void getRandomBytes(u8 **str, u32 len) {
    int fd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);
    char *ptr = malloc((size_t) + 1);

    read(fd, ptr, len);
    close(fd);

    ptr[len] = '\0';
    *str = ptr; 
}
```

Results are like:

> Encrypting [THIS IS A TEST] using random 256 bit key and 64 bit IV:
>   And now decrypting back: [(bunch of random characters)]

Where it should be:

> And now decrypting back: [THIS IS A TEST]

Feel free to provide your solution in either C or C++

Thank you!

Comment: How are you supposing to implement such an application in C/C++ if you C knowledge is rusty? Have you tried looking up any sample code? What have you tried in general? And is this a repost? I seem to recollect another question about Salsa20 which I cannot find anymore.

Comment: Number one hint about C: It's *not C++*.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question to provide some sample code I've written so far till I hit a dead-end. You can see, my C is rusty- but not entirely non-existant. It's like riding a bike I guess :) 

Unfortunately, I've found complex samples online (like the eSTREAM test suite) and samples in other languages... but no direct simple implementation in C (probably because I'm just missing some basic concept here which is supposed to be self-evident).

I haven't seen another post which asks this exact question.

Comment: DeadMG: Is the salsa20.c file provided at eSTREAM not valid C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use Salsa20 in real code and you are asking questions like this, you probably want to use the NaCl library with nice friendly C++ wrappers.

See [The NaCl website](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/).

To answer your actual question: you need to set the IV up again for the decryption operation. The IV consists of your nonce and a block offset. The encrypt/decrypt functions increment the offset, giving your code a different IV for the encryption and decryption functions.

Comment: Thanks janm- adding ECRYPT_ivsetup(&ctx, IV); right before ECRYPT_decrypt_bytes() did the trick. Works when I enable the getRandomBytes() stuff too :)

And thanks for the link to NaCl- that's great!

Question- now that I have it working with the one block of 1024 bytes, assuming that I now want to read/write from a much larger file.... can I use the same nonce to re-initialize the IV each time (right before each call to ECRYPT_encrypt_bytes()), or must I change the nonce for each read/write?

Comment: @davidkomer: Salsa20 has 64 byte blocks, so you need feed the encrypt/decrypt functions a multiple of 64 bytes until your last block. Use a unique 64 bit message number as the nonce and let the library increment the block number. You only need to set up the IV at the start of the message, not before each block. Setting up the IV before each block will weaken security by reusing block numbers, so don't do that.

Comment: got it, thanks :) If the last chunk is < 64 bytes, I can just pad with NULLs right?

Comment: The IV is safe to transmit as plaintext, i.e. appending straight to the front of the output, yeah?

Comment: The library will pad for you, but you can do it too. Yes, the IV is safe to transmit as plaintext.

Comment: Now that I've got this working... any hints on how to change the IV to enable seeking to a position in the byte stream (assume its a multiple of 64)?

Comment: @davidkomer Just happened to see this old comment, probably replying much too late to be useful! Set the block number part of the IV to the block number where you're starting.